# Is there a way to make IDEs (IntelliJ, PyCharm, VS Code) have fewer popups but still have completion?

Tags: intellij-idea, visual-studio-code, pycharm

I learned to program 30 years ago with Emacs. I'm starting to learn moderns IDEs such as "IntelliJ IDEA", "PyCharm", and "VS Code".

It's hard to adjust to how visually "busy" they are, with constant pop-up menus appearing every character I type.

Of course I want to be able to get suggestions for completion or parameter hints or other popups when necessary. I just don't want them to appear by default.

Some people are asking why popups are annoying. The main problem is that popups cover code above or below where I'm typing.

Emacs has completion. But it doesn't need a popup. For instance, dynamic completion works just fine 90% of the time, even though it's not smart enough to parse syntax or look up function and method definitions.

So I'd like to know if there are settings in JetBrains or VS Code IDE's that would help.

I'm aware of two kinds of popups.
(1) An offer to complete my typing, which appears below.
(2) Annotation of argument names and definitions, which appears above.

There may be other popups as well.

I'm aware that a popup can be dismissed with `ESC`. But often they just come back the moment you type another character.

What would be great is if the popup would not appear by default, but I could cause it to appear with a single keystroke. Or I could dismiss it and it would stay dismissed.

Answer (score 1):

For **PyCharm** You can also try writing in "Disctraction Free Mode"

View -> Enter Distraction Free Mode

Which should give you a little screen of calm which will feel a lot more like emacs to you.

Answer (score 0):

The new IDEs are really busy looking for libraries, checking/auto closing balanced parentheses, indenting, surrounding methods/functions/procedures/classes as you type. Sometimes I feel the same, but these IDEs are not plain text editors anymore. Every key stroke triggers something which can be time consuming. When the project gets larger and when it has lots of libraries, it can get even slower. Some IDEs have options to turn some of these options off. Every feature turned off will have some positive effect on responsiveness to some degree

But I think, instead of turning these features off, the best way to have these features on a responsive modern IDE is to use a computer with a fast cpu, an ssd drive and sufficient memory.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what I mean by "busy". I don't mean the computer is working. I mean the visual appearance of the IDE is filled with movement and change, words popping-up, etc. In American English a cluttered environment is said to "look busy."

Comment: What OP said. See definitions 2, 3, and 4 of *busy* [here](https://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=busy). Cluttered, noisy, distracting, annoying...

Comment: Would be great to see an example of an annoying pop-up. What can they be? For ex; if I have a function named as checkPatientAddress in an other module and then later on when I start typing with ch.. and if it shows up with recommendations, I appreciate it :)

Comment: Any popup that covers code I need to read is an annoying popup. That goes double if there was no use for it in that particular moment. That goes triple if it's a popup that I could always call up by will via Ctrl-Space or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to adjust the behaviour via "Settings".
In IntelliJ IDEA, goto Menu `File` --> `Settings ...` , then navigate to `Editor` --> `General` --> `Code Completion` , or type something in the search field (upper left).

Perhaps you find more settings when you browse through Settings dialog.

To be honest, I didn't make a lot of tests with these settings, because I find the helper popups very useful.

[image]

Another option to get rid of some "noise" is to adjust settings for displaying parameter names in the code editor.
[image]

I switched this off completely.
Go to `Settings` --> `Editor` --> `General` --> `Appearance`

[image]

Comment: I find them useful **sometimes** as well, so I want to be able to call them up optionally. I see that in some IDE's you can disable completion, but then type ctrl-space to bring the popup as necessary. How about parameter popups or other kinds? How about VS Code rather than JetBrains? These are my questions.